# AccessibilityEvent.getPackageName() returns null

Tags: java, android, accessibilityservice

I am registering an AccessibilityService to listen for app changes. It works on all the phones I've tested but on the Galaxy A3 with Android 5.0 is failing because **AccessibilityEvent.getPackageName()** is returning **null**. The packageName should be set, as it is a regular app, downloaded from Google play, being interacted with.

Does anyone know why is this and how to fix it?

Below the relevant parts of my code.

```
<service
    android:name=".presentation.view.services.LockService"
    android:permission="android.permission.BIND_ACCESSIBILITY_SERVICE">
    <meta-data
        android:name="android.accessibilityservice"
        android:resource="@xml/accessibility_service_config"/>

    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.accessibilityservice.AccessibilityService"/>
    </intent-filter>
 </service>
```

```
@Override
public void onServiceConnected() {
  AccessibilityServiceInfo info = new AccessibilityServiceInfo();

  info.eventTypes = AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_WINDOW_STATE_CHANGED;
  info.feedbackType = AccessibilityServiceInfo.FEEDBACK_GENERIC;
  info.notificationTimeout = 100;

  this.setServiceInfo(info);
}

@Override
public void onAccessibilityEvent(AccessibilityEvent event) {
  event.getPackageName() // returns NULL;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As the documentation doesn't specifically explain this, I'll try to provide something that I've came up with after playing around with the `AccessibilityService`. I'm writing this just in case others are banging their heads because `event.getPackageName()` always returns `null`, but don't take my word for granted.

From the documentation of accessibility service, I see that you can set the attribute `android:packageNames="@strings/blah_blah"`, where `blah_blah` is a comma separated list of package names that our service will observe.

In case we specify this attribute, we will get notified only for those specific packages and `event.getPackageName()` will return the proper package name.

If we leave this attribute unset or we specifically set this to `null` we will be notified of all events that occur, but we'll lose the ability to identify whichever specific package "generated" the accessibility event.

As this `AccessibilityServiceInfo` property can be dynamically set, you could in theory fetch a list of currently installed packages and set that as the `packageNames` that your service will monitor.

```
@Override
protected void onServiceConnected() {
    super.onServiceConnected();
    AccessibilityServiceInfo info = getServiceInfo();
    // your other assignments
    info.packageNames = new String[]{...};
    setServiceInfo(info);
}
```